# Comparing files from different project

Tags: webstorm

I have two projects and I want to verify if content of two files in the 2nd project is the same, so I wonder if it is possible to compare two files from two different projects (in two instances of the IDE)

Comment: Well ... 1) you can always open file and copy its' content to Clipboard in 1st project and then use "Compare with Clipboard" in another. 2) You can add 2nd project folder(s) as "Additional Content Root" in 1st one .. and then just compare 2 files in IDE (as they all will be available in Project View panel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file in the editor and then use the Compare with... action (you can find it using Find action popup - Cmd/Ctrl-Shift-A) and select the file you want to compare it with.